# How do I get DVORAK keyboard layout on Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout, dvorak

There is no such layout by default and I have tried getting the one available here (http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/) and it doesn't work with Windows. So is there any way I get the DVORAK layout on Windows?

Comment: For future reference, you can add Dvorak as the primary layout during the Windows install process, too.  Just select it from the dropdown list on the opening install screen.

Comment: My assumption of DVORAK layout not existing by default was completely wrong. I was looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Is it possible to have an onscreen layout displayed at all time for training purposes.

Comment: If you need onscreen layout just launch the On-Screen Keyboard

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo Thanks. I keep forgetting what Windows actually has. I was using the touch keyboard from the taskbar and it disappears every time I type using my keyboard. Totally forgot that an on-screen keyboard existed.

Comment: Regarding Programmer Dvorak there are several others that have installed it on Windows 8, so there must be something in particular with your system if it doesn't work (neither do you specify *how* it doesn't work).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the Control Panel select Language and then Options:

[image: Language Panel]

In the Input method select Add an input method:

[image: Options Panel]

From there you can select the DVORAK R or L keyboards

[image: Input Options]

Comment: You haven't even written what version of windows you are talking about.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx) to create any keyboard layout you want. It even contains DVORAK layouts to get you started.

1. Click **File** → **Load Existing Keyboard...**
2. [image]

Comment: It seems that DLL files created with this software can not be used with Windows 8 (at least not on 64bit).

Comment: I tried this and created one, but can't figure out how to get this to be my standard keyboard.

Comment: @W00d5t0ck Nope, Windows 8 x64 and Windows 8.1 x64 both support custom keyboard layouts. Been using my custom keyboard since Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I see an option in Windows 7 here

[image]