# Can I Use My Win8 On Screen Keyboard On A Win10 PC?

Tags: windows-10, on-screen-keyboard

I'm disabled so I type with an on screen keyboard, Microsoft's Win8 on screen keyboard.
I'm used to this layout and I'm afraid that if I get a Win10 PC I won't be able to use Win8 on screen keyboard on it.
Can I install Win8 on screen keyboard on a Win10 PC?
I know Win10 has a keyboard too, I tested it, and the layout isn't good for me, I need this layout:
[Win8 OSK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjIej.png)

Also, is there a software that can take Win8 on screen keyboard layout and edit the buttons & settings?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to open On-Screen keyboard on Windows 10 too.

**To open the On-Screen Keyboard:**
Go to Start , then select **Settings > Ease of Access > Keyboard**, and then move the slider under On-Screen Keyboard. A keyboard appears on the screen that can be used to move around the screen and enter text. The keyboard will remain on the screen until you close it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 has an on-screen keyboard. You might try a Windows 10 machine from a friend or in a store to see if it already meets your needs. This is the default layout:

[image: Win 10 on-scream Kbd]

[WinSuperSite](http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/how-change-between-different-onscreen-keyboard-options-windows-10) mentions some of the Windows 10 options:

1. Language preference
2. Split-keyboard option
3. Full-sized keyboard option

And [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/548441/how-do-i-get-dvorak-keyboard-layout-on-windows-8) (of course!) explains how to change the keyboard layout, such as the various Dvořák options, using *Control Panel* -> *Language* -> *Options* -> *Add an input method*. When selecting language, the keyboard is displayed (mostly) in the new alphabet:

[image]

Comment: Edited my question to be more specific