# Is it possible to change the keyboard layout when no operating system is installed on the computer?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout, computer-building

I installed ubuntu on my pc. I think there was a bug and it opened GNU GRUB command line. I can't write commands there because I am a dvorak user. If this happens to me in future again, I want to change my system keyboard layout. Is there a thing like that?

Comment: Have you seen https://askubuntu.com/questions/751259/how-to-change-grub-command-line-grub-shell-keyboard-layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, it could potentially be done with an extra computer(call it computer A). So, the keyboard is plugged into Computer A, and a USB cable plugs Computer A i into computer B's USB(your computer B is your computer with no OS). Computer A would run software that would read input from the keyboard, and change it in memory, and send it down the USB cable to Computer B. And so as far as computer B was concerned, a keyboard is attached. And you'd have full control over the layout of it.

Now for in practise

I looked up "hardware key remapper". And somebody did something with an arduino, 
https://forum.colemak.com/topic/1561-arduinobased-hardware-keyboard-remapper/   but that is a very strange use of an arduino and it's not entirely clear to me how he managed to read from a USB keyboard or write to USB with it, but in theory it's possible and it seems he did it.  More typical basic uses of Arduino involve inputting from and outputting to little electronic components that one might put in a breadboard, so maybe he chopped up a USB cable and found a way to correctly interpret data coming from a keyboard. And a way to write in a way that suits writing to USB and in a way that emulates a keyboard.  He has linked to his code, so that may help.  There is a video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RoG_-9lAnSI  Where somebody shows what to do on the hardware level to get an Arduino to act as a keyboard. His video shows that it seems he managed to get a USB 'B type socket soldered onto his Arduino. And he may have cut open a USB cable too.  There are probably many other videos on youtube of Arduino reading or writing to USB.  If you used a computer, even a small computer like a Raspberry Pi then it'd already have a USB socket on there for reading and writing, so it'd be easier, then you'd just need to know how to read and write to USB in your programming language. And how to interpret keyboard input. And how to send data down USB in a way that emulates a keyboard. But from a hardware perspective, i'd think things would be easier with a computer rather than an Arduino.

This guy has done keyboard input or writing  / emulation, with a Raspberry Pi(basically a very small computer), you see the hardware is much easier than with an Arduino, as a Raspberry Pi has one or even two USB connectors (And if it only had one then you can probably use a USB hub). The Raspberry Pi in the video has 2 USB connectors which is perfect for you  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-tC7nL7rVRE   Still a project though as you have to program it (which might not be that hard as lots of code is available online) and you'd have to get your Pi set up, that part is standard. But all the hardware is there for you unlike the Arduino that is more barebones.

Comment: Does that mean, I have to tick mark English US in order to use English Dvorak in a OS?

Comment: @HarshitKhandelwal that's a very different question, but there are options for dvorak in windows, see here  https://superuser.com/questions/548441/how-do-i-get-dvorak-keyboard-layout-on-windows/1417537#1417537